# Moments method and plug-in method

Tags: estimators, method-of-moments

We have the following discrete distribution on $\{1,2,3\}$:
$$\mathbb{P}(X=1)= \theta^2, \mathbb{P}(X=2) = 2\theta(1-\theta), \mathbb{P}(X=3)=(1-\theta)^2$$

with $\theta \in (0,1)$ and want to use both plug-in estimator as well as moments method.

I calculate the 
$\mathbb{E}(X) = \theta^2 + 2 \cdot 2\theta(1-\theta) + 3 \cdot (1-\theta) = -2\theta + 3$ and the moment estimator is as follows:

$$-2 \hat{\theta} + 3 = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_n \implies \hat{\theta} = \frac{1}{2}\left(3 - \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i\right)$$

Now, I'd like to estimate $\theta$ with plug-in method. Since I've already calculated the $\mathbb{E}X$ and the plug-in estimator of that is just arithmetic mean, does that mean the plug-in method equals the moments method? If not, how does the plug-in method look like?

I am looking for a simple discrete example of plug-in method too, as I had only seen the theory part with no examples.

Comment: I do not see $\theta$ as a natural statistic of the population, and so I so not see a *plug-in* estimator .  It is true that $\theta=\frac12(3-\mathbb E(X)$, but it is also true that $\theta = \sqrt{\mathbb P(X=1)}$ and these lead to different estimators, neither of which look *plug-in*.

Comment: Isn't $X - 1 \sim \mathsf{Binom}(2, \theta)?$

Comment: If yes, how can I use that fact with plug-in method?